# How to avoid swipeup while doing pinch zoom with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm facing the problem of `swipe up` is happening when doing pinch zoom on image

**Question :** how to avoid `swipeup`  while doing pinch `zoom` ?

As you know we do pinch zoom with 2 fingers simultaneously  but `swipeup` with a single finger

Here is what my  current code looks like :

```js
          let swipeUpY;
           const zoomContainer = document.getElementById('zoomContainer');
          zoomContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
            // Record the starting Y-coordinate when the touch starts
            swipeUpY = e.touches[0].clientY;
          });


zoomContainer.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
            // Calculate the change in Y-coordinate
            const deltaY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY - swipeUpY;

            const swipeUpThreshold = 50;
            const swipeDownThreshold = -50;

            if (deltaY < swipeDownThreshold) { // Swipe Up
              console.log('Swipe Up Detected!');
            } else if (deltaY > swipeUpThreshold) { // Swipe down
              console.log('Swipe Down Detected!');
            }
          });
```

```css
.image-preview-with-zoom{
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
}

.image-preview-with-zoom img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-preview-with-zoom" id="zoomContainer">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white"/>
</div>
```